# How can i toggle components based on selector change?

Tags: angular

I have a selector that lets a user change their chosen payment method. That calls a component called PaymentComponent that is "supposed" to listen for the change in Selector in the parent component and then toggle the appropriate payment method component (i.e. WireTransferPayment, CheckPayment, CreditCardPayment) but right now that doesn't work. In fact, the PaymentComponent doesn't even register that the selector has changed. I'm still learning Angular2 so I realize I'm still missing something simple. Can someone point me in the right direction? My google foo is failing me right now.

```
PARENT COMPONENT

@Component {
  template: '
    <select (change)="onPaymentTypeChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control" id="paymentType" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>select payment type to begin</option>
      <option value="pmtCreditCard">Credit Card</option>
      <option value="pmtCheck">Check</option>
      <option value="pmtWire">Wire Transfer</option>
    </select>
    <app-payment [paymentTypeSelector]="paymentType"></app-payment>
  '
}
export class ParentComponent {
  onPaymentTypeChange(selectorValue) {
    console.log('paymentType ', this.paymentType);
    console.log('selectorValue ', selectorValue);
    this.paymentType = selectorValue;
  }
}


CHILD COMPONENT

@Component {
  inputs: [ 'paymentTypeSelector' ],
}

export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  paymentTypeSelector: string;
  displayCheck = 'none';
  displayWire = 'none';

  constructor() {
    console.log('paymentTypeSelected', this.paymentTypeSelector);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('here: ', this.paymentTypeSelector);
    this.togglePaymentDisplay(this.paymentTypeSelector)
  }

  togglePaymentDisplay(paymentType) {
    console.log('paymentTypeSelected', paymentType);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? What did you try so far?

Comment: @rinukkusu you're right. here's a synopsis of what i've tried.

Comment: have a look at this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html and read about @Input() and @Ouput() directives

Comment: @rashfmnb i have in this case, I want the child to listen for changes from the parent. right now, whenever the selector changes, the child component never responds. @output() seems directed towards the child talking to the parent, and @input() doesn't do anything right now. :(

Comment: Then you need to create the service to communicate between these two check this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out the solution, `NgChanges` was what I needed.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-payment',
  templateUrl: 'payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['payment.component.css'],
  directives: [
    CheckPaymentComponent,
    WireTransferPaymentComponent
  ],
})
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() name: string;
  changeLog: string[] = [];

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propkey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    let log: string[] = [];
    console.log('log ', log);
    for (let propName in changes) {
      console.log('propName ', propName);
      let changedProp = changes[propName];
      let from = JSON.stringify(changedProp.previousValue);
      let to =   JSON.stringify(changedProp.currentValue);
      log.push( `${propName} changed from ${from} to ${to}`);
    }
    this.changeLog.push(log.join(', '));
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```